# ping behind firewall, success for some hosts, fail for others?

Tags: firewall, ping

I'm under firewall, I can ping to some hosts but not to other hosts

my IP addresss `172.19.7.111` `mask 255.255.240.0`

I  can ping to host `172.19.2.111` (that I discovered with Angry IP Scanner) but not to `172.19.2.167` which is my rapsberry.

I checked both host  IP address with `ifconfig`. both have `mask 255.255.240.0`

hosts not reached are not detected by Angry IP Scanner.

Scanning network for open ports with nmap command for host 172.19.2.167 (wlan0)

`nmap -v  -sT 172.19.4.47 -Pn`

```
 Completed Connect Scan at 20:28, 14.39s elapsed (1000 total ports)
    Nmap scan report for 172.19.4.167
    Host is up (0.11s latency).
    All 1000 scanned ports on 172.19.4.167 are filtered
```

I can ping this host 1"72.19.4.167" via eth0 (192.168.0.0 /24 network )

Scanning with eth0 network (1952.168.0.0/24) (same host)

Initiating Connect Scan at 21:20
Scanning 192.168.0.2 [1000 ports]

```
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.0.2
Completed Connect Scan at 21:20, 0.14s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.2
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:D5:44:B8 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

gateway scan (172.19.0.5)

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-28 21:12 CEST
Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 21:12
Scanning 172.19.0.5 [1 port]
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 21:12, 0.02s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:12
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:12, 0.01s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 21:12
Scanning pftw01.crous.lan (172.19.0.5) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 53/tcp on 172.19.0.5
Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 172.19.0.5
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 172.19.0.5
Discovered open port 8000/tcp on 172.19.0.5
Discovered open port 8001/tcp on 172.19.0.5
Completed Connect Scan at 21:12, 4.41s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for pftw01.crous.lan (172.19.0.5)
Host is up (0.0045s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
53/tcp   open  domain
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8001/tcp open  vcom-tunnel
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:D4:41:EB (VMware)
```

any explanations???

Comment: Please give us more details about your network, the source and destination devices. What kind of hardware is it? How the devices are connected? Where are the firewall connected and so on ...

Comment: I have my laptop (172.19.7.110), raspberry (172.19.4.167), I  can ping and ssh rapsberry via eth0 (192.168.0.0/24) but not via wlan0 (172.19.X.X/255.255.240.0), but I discovered other IP address with Angry IP Scanner (172.19.2.111) that I can ping

Answer (score 0):

172.19.7.111/20 & 172.19.2.111/20  are on the same subnet. 172.192.2.167 is definitely on a different subnet. I think you need to add rules to forward packets between the two subnets.

Comment: sorry I mean I can ping to host 172.19.2.111 but not to 172.19.2.167

Comment: Does the destination machine have any firewall rule to ignore ICMP Echo Requests? If you know that a firewall is in place, you might want to modify the rules to work for you.

Comment: if the firewall ignore ICMP, how can I ping successfully to 172.19.2.111 ???, and why Angry Ip Scanner cant detect the other host who has 172.19.2.167 IP ??

Comment: for IP address, 172.19.2.111 I detected it by Angry Ip Scanner, im not sure that is ordinary host, there is other IP address like that in this network where I can ping

Comment: I did not mean a firewall between the two machines. I meant the firewall on the machine itself. Something like a firewall software on the remote machine itself, such as iptables on Linux. The successful ping could be to a machine that does not ignore ICMP echo requests.

Comment: im under linux I can't ping to host 172.19.2.167 who is my raspberry IP address, but I can ping to it via lan eth0 interface. is it mean that iptables doest represent any problem??

Comment: can you please please do a "cat /etc/iptables/simple_firewall.rules" to see if your RPi actually has rules to accept ICMP packets... And also, if you want to port scan, try to disable pings before scanning. I assume that you can SSH into your RPi now, so it might be a simple issue with iptables.

Comment: file cat /etc/iptables/simple_firewall.rules dont exist. I'm connecting to raspberry via eth0 (192.168.0.0/24) when I scan port with nmap command I got PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:D5:44:B8 (Raspberry Pi Foundation) and when I scan port via wlan0 (172.19.X.X/240) I got Completed Connect Scan at 20:28, 14.39s elapsed (1000 total ports)
    Nmap scan report for 172.19.4.167
    Host is up (0.11s latency).
    All 1000 scanned ports on 172.19.4.167 are filtered

Comment: Well... If I understand correctly... when you ping through eth0(192.168.x.x) you get through to your RPi which is most likely in that range too. So Your RPi is in the range of (192.168.x.x). Pinging from a different subnet wont be routed through... I do hope this helps. If I got it totally wrong, please tell me what interfaces you have on the RPi

Comment: im connecting to raspberry via two interface eth0 (192.168.0.0/24) connected directly from my pc to raspberry (RJ47) (pc:192.168.0.1 RPI:192.168.0.2)  and wlan0 (172.19.x.x 255.255.240.0) which is university network (PC 172.19.7.110, RPI 172.19.2.167) (255.255.240.0). I can ping and ssh via eth0 but I can ping or ssh via wlan0.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you have any security measures on the hotspots on campus? Like client isolation or something on the Wifi hotspots, thus preventing associated clients from communicating? A good place to start is to check if you can connect two computers connected to the WLAN. If they won't connect, then there is no way to fix that. port scanners like nmap ping(-P0) before they scan, if you want to give it a shot, see how you can disable ping for your portscanner.

Comment: thank you Ghassan, I think that as you said the hotspot have client isolation, I can ssh to remote host http://sdf.org/ , I can connect two hosts of my wlan with teamviewer. so I think that a solution is to  connect my raspberry with external service like teamviewer did, any idea? thanks

Comment: You can create an Ad-hoc network connecting between the two machines if you want. They will be able to communicate wirelessly without the help of the access point. And you are welcome, Mekhlouf :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get an answer from the host that will be inside a private network 172.19.2.111 but not from the public internet 172.192.2.167 - Please look at [list of private networks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958825.aspx)
 - only 172.16.0.1 to 172.31.255.254 are private networks - every ip address outside these range will be routed into internet.

Comment: sorry I mean I can ping to host 172.19.2.111 but not to 172.19.2.167,